# How to skip one of multiple optional route parameter in Node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have a simple route like the following:

```
app.get("/posts/:country?/:city?", function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

How may I *skip* `country` but only define `city` (when necessary), both of which are optional parameters? In other words, I would like to have `undefined` for `country` but a value for `city`.

Ideally, how could something like this `/posts//paris` be achieved, without having to do `/posts/france/paris`?

If that is not possible, what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Double-slashes in the path-part of a URL are frowned upon. I would suggest two routes, one for `/posts/:city` and one for `/posts/:country/:city`. If only to make it a bit easier on your future self.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply send a request to the following url: `/posts/1/Berlin`

Basically any value you want and you're sure your `country` param cannot take. Then use an `if` to determine the case where the `country` is not sent.

In other words, whenever you send `1` for `country`, you know that in that case you don't get a country.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution on the official documentation here https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html. It's not exactly as I initially thought it could be implemented, however it fulfils the requirement sufficiently.

```
app.get("/posts/country/:country?/city/:city?", function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("/");
});
```